# PDF digital signing: customize appearance by using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a pdf file by using iTextSharp 5.5.9. When customize appearance, I received an error which is unintelligible. Here what I did

Sign method:

```
public void Sign1(String src, String name, String dest, ICollection<X509Certificate> chain, ICipherParameters pk, String digestAlgorithm, CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
        {
            // Creating the reader and the stamper
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
            // Creating the appearance
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Reason = reason;
            appearance.Location = location;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(name);
            // Custom text and custom font
            appearance.Layer2Text = "This document was signed by ABC";
            appearance.Layer2Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN);
            // Creating the signature
            IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm);
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
        }
```

and way I signed

```
String KEYSTORE = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/temp.pfx";
char[] PASSWORD = "blabla".ToCharArray();
String SRC = "C:/Users/user/abc.pdf";
String DEST = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/aaa.pdf";
 Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(KEYSTORE, FileMode.Open), PASSWORD);
            String alias = "";
            ICollection<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
            // searching for private key

            foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
                if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
                {
                    alias = al;
                    break;
                }

            AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);
            foreach (X509CertificateEntry c in store.GetCertificateChain(alias))
                chain.Add(c.Certificate);

            RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters parameters = pk.Key as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
Sign1(SRC, "Signature1", String.Format(DEST, 1), chain, parameters, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, CryptoStandard.CMS, "Customize apprearance", "Blabla");
```

And message I received:
[image: message]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an error which is unintelligible

On the contrary, it clearly states that some argument value is not appropriate, and the additional information even indicate which argument value and for which reason:

> The field Signature1 does not exist.

"Signature1" is the value you use as signature field name, and your `Sign1` method uses it here:

```
appearance.SetVisibleSignature(name);
```

The method you call is documented in the sources like this:

```
/**
 * Sets the signature to be visible. An empty signature field with the same name must already exist.
 * @param fieldName the existing empty signature field name
 */
virtual public void SetVisibleSignature(String fieldName)
```

but your PDF does not yet seem to have *an empty signature field with the same name* which triggers the exception you observe.

If you want to sign (with in-document visualization of the signature) a PDF but cannot use an existing empty signature field, you have to use a different overload of that method to which you provide the necessary information to create a signature field visualization:

```
/**
 * Sets the signature to be visible. It creates a new visible signature field.
 * @param pageRect the position and dimension of the field in the page
 * @param page the page to place the field. The fist page is 1
 * @param fieldName the field name or <CODE>null</CODE> to generate automatically a new field name
 */
virtual public void SetVisibleSignature(Rectangle pageRect, int page, String fieldName)
```

Comment: Thank mkl. I have to create empty field before signing.